# C# Async function projected to property

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I have a situation where I am trying to do the following:

```
var someData = previousResult
     .Select(x => new 
      {
         Id = x.Id,
         SomeAsyncThing = _repo.AsyncThing(x.A, x.B)
      });

await Task.WhenAll(someData.Select(x => x.SomeAsyncThing));
```

I am wondering if this will work, or if the Select will create a copy of the list and await that copy

EDIT:

I have tried the following in a separate, smaller project.

```
public class SampleClass
    {
        public async Task<bool> TestAsync(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting " + x);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<bool> CallMe()
        {
            var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
            var projection = list.Select(x => new {
                Id = x,
                Hello = TestAsync(x)
            }).ToList();

            await Task.WhenAll(projection.Select(x => x.Hello));

            projection.ForEach(x => {
                Console.WriteLine("Finished " + x.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Result: " + x.Hello);
            });
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is the class that is running this

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new SampleClass().CallMe().Result;
        }
    }
```

This outputs the following:
[image: console output]

Comment: The `Select` will just creates a deferred enumerable. No tasks will be created/started at this point. But when you feed this enumerable to `Task.WhenAll`, it will be materialized immediately to an array, causing the creation of all tasks at once. You won't be able to access these tasks later. If you do want to access them, you need to materialize the enumerable before feeding it to `Task.WhenAll`. To do it it's enough to chain the `ToArray` (or `ToList`) LINQ method to the enumerable.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am still new to C# and async programming in general. So, if in my example, I add a `.ToList()` to the end of the first `.Select()`, the tasks will be created/started at that point? Ultimately, I want to await the task in a specific property of a projected object and have the result be available within that property.

Comment: Invoking some non-async thing; `.Select(x => _repo.Thing(x))`, will only happen when iterating through the enumeration. Enumerating more than once will invoke the thing more than once. Adding async to the problem doesn't really change that.

Comment: Right. But, I would have the response to that method call immediately. In the async scenario, I am projecting the async method call to a property on an object. I want to await this collection of objects based on the Task for the `SomeAsyncThing` resolving.

Comment: _"I am wondering if this will work"_ -- did it work when you tried it? if so, why are you asking this question? if not, what part of why it didn't work do you have trouble understanding? (Hint: it works. You should be testing your code, not asking this question.)

Comment: I have added code that I tested but I have inconsistent results. I am unsure if my calling `.Result` at the end of `x.Hello` will cause the thread to wait for the result, or if my `await Task.WhenAll` has succeeded and the value is available in `.Result` without waiting separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be aware of what an IEnumerable is.

An IEnumerable represents a sequence of items. It holds everything to enumerate this sequence: you can ask for the first element, and once you've got an element, you can ask for the next one, as long as there is a next one.

At its lowest level, this enumerating is done using functions like GetEnumerator and MoveNext. Once you've got an element, you can access it using property Current.

```
IEnumerable<Order> orders = ...;
var orderEnumerator = orders.GetEnumerator();
while (orderEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
    Order order = orderEnumerator.Current;
    ProcessOrder(order);
}
```

If you use foreach, the compiler will call GetEnumerator() and MoveNext()/Current for you.

If you look closer to LINQ, you'll see that there are two types of LINQ methods: the ones that return `IEnumerable<...>`, and the ones that don't.

Examples of the first group are: Select, GroupBy, (Group)Join, etc. They all use deferred execution: concatenating LINQ methods of this group won't start enumerating the sequence. The result of a function in this group represents another Enumerable sequence: the sequence is not enumerated.

Examples of the latter group are ToList(), ToDictionary(), Count(), FirstOrDefault(), Any(). As soon as you call them, the sequence is enumerated, or to be exact: GetEnumerator() is called, and MoveNext() is called until the result of the function is known. ToList() will call method MoveNext() until it MoveNext() returns false, indicating that there are no more elements. For Any(), MoveNext() is only called once:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    return enumerator.MoveNext();
}
```

If MoveNext returns true, you know that the sequence contains at least one element.

### Back to your question

If you use your debugger to look at the value of `SomeData`, you'll see that it is an `IEnumerable<...>`: the query is not execute yet.

Even the code

```
someData.Select(x => x.SomeAsyncThing)
```

does not execute the query. Your debugger will say that it is still an `IEnumerable<...>`

> I am wondering if this will work, or if the Select will create a copy of the list and await that copy

Yes, it will work, and no, Select won't create a copy of the list, because until WhenAll there wasn't a List.

`Task.WhenAll` accepts an `IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>` as input. If you look at the [reference source of Task.WhenAll](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs) you'll see that it first checks whether the input is an array or an ICollection. If not, it will use foreach to convert your sequence into a List of tasks.

**That is the moment that method repo.AsyncThing(...) is called for the first time**, using x.A and x.B of the first element of previousResult.

Your thread will continue executing the statements inside the AsyncThing, until it sees an await (or until a Task is returned). The thread will go up the call stack and execute the next element of the sequence: `repo.AsyncThing` with x.A and x.B of the second element of previousResult.

This goes on until the complete sequence of Tasks is put in a List. After that your thread awaits, until all tasks in the list are completed.

### So my code is correct then?

That depends on what you want to do. Because you also Select the Id, it seems to me that you want as a result a sequence of Ids, together with the awaited result of the Task.

If you want to access the elements of this sequence, your code is not good.

**Why?**

As I wrote before: someData is an IEnumerable. As soon as you think that all tasks are finished, and you want the first Id and the first SomeAsyncThing, you start enumerating and a _repo.AsyncThing is called again, resulting in a new awaitable task.

I think you don't want to start the tasks every time you start enumerating your sequence.

My advice would be:

```
var someData = previousResult
 .Select(x => new 
  {
     Id = x.Id,
     SomeAsyncThing = await _repo.AsyncThing(x.A, x.B)
  });
```

Note the await before _repo.AsyncThing.

As before: as long as the list is not enumerated, AsyncThing is not called. If you want to be certain that will be called only once, convert someData  to a List or an Array and then use Task.WhenAll:

```
var someDataList = someData.ToList();
```

Now every element of the someDataList is an object with an Id and an awaitableTask.

Note: enumerating someDataList won't start the task again. After the ToList the LINQ statements in SomeData are executed, only the result is in SomeDataList.

All you have to do is await every task:

```
await Task.WhenAll(someDataList.Select(someData => someData.SomeAsyncThing).
```

Note: this does not change someDataList, it is still a List, where every element has an Id and an awaitable Task. The only thing that is changed, is that you are certain that every awaitable Task is completed.

So to access the results of the tasks:

```
var taskResults = someDataList.Select(someData => new
{
    Id = someData.Id,
    TaskResult = someData.SomeAsyncThing.Result,
});
```

Note: by now, you should know that taskResults is not enumerated yet. Therefore the Results of the tasks are not fetched until you MoveNext() to the element. You'll probably end this with:

var taskResultCollection = taskResults.ToList();

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I was able to add a `.Result` at the end of `x.Hello` and it displayed properly and it didn't hang the thread. This is because the line above it `await Task.WhenAll` populates the .Result property. The value is then accessible in constant speed and does not block the thread accessing the property. I reconfirmed by checking this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8